# How to add a title that redirects to a link

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, wordpress

Using the "Import All" WordPress plugin, I am importing an Excel file with a large number of hyperlinks that are directed to certain Custom Post Types and a specific field. These hyperlinks are separated by commas from the title. Example:

```
"here hyperlink","title of page".
```

How do I make a link that says "Title of the page" appear and that when clicked redirects to the link?

Actually I just have this:

```
if (!empty($materiales_complementarios) &&
    $materiales_complementarios) {

    echo '<b>Materiales complementarios</b><br> ';
    echo '<ul>';
    $materiales_complementarios_array = explode("\n", $materiales_complementarios);

    foreach ($materiales_complementarios_array as $mc) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<a href="' . $mc . '" target="_blank">Ingresa aquí</a>';
        echo '</li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on the comma... Assuming you don't have any other commas in that line (`$mc`), this will do the trick:

```
echo '<a href="' . explode(',', $mc)[0] . '" target="_blank">' . explode(',', $mc)[1] . '</a>';
```

It's a simple `explode` while calling the `index` of each exploded item. That is, `[0]` and `[1]`.

Comment: Thanks! Im new in this haha. It works, thanks!